# changing image src in span using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 5 span elements and 5 images in them.

```
    <div id="myDiv">
    <span class="fwheeler"><img src="car1.jpg"/></span>
    <span class="fwheeler"><img src="car1.jpg"/></span>
    <span class="fwheeler"><img src="car1.jpg"/></span>
    <span class="fwheeler"><img src="car1.jpg"/></span>
    <span class="fwheeler"><img src="car1.jpg"/></span>
    </div>
```

and i have one button like this

```
<button type="button" id="park1">Park</button>
```

If i click on the button the src of the span:img should change. for this i am using

```
$("img").attr('src', '\car.jpg');
```

This is replacing all images src. But my requirement is, if i click on the button for the first time, only first span's image src should change. if i click 2nd time, both 1st and 2nd should change and so on..

How can i do this.

Comment: try changing $("img").attr('src', '\car.jpg'); to $("img").attr('src', '/car.jpg');

Comment: no problem with that. it is working if i use "\" also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

then put a global variable that counts no of clicks.

then use

```
 <button type="button" id="park1">Park</button>

    <script>
    var count = 0;
     $('#park1').click(function(){
       if(count< $('#myDiv span').length){        
       $("img").eq(count).attr('src', '\car.jpg'); 
      count++;
     }else{
        count=0;
     }
 });    
</script>
```

Comment: Nice, except for the use of inline javascript in the onClick :(

Answer (score 3):

count the clicked value into global var..... use eq() to change the src attribute..
try this

```
var clickCount=0;
$('#park1').click(function(){  
     if(clickcount < $('#myDiv span').length){  //check the length of span if clickCount is greater make it 0.... so that you get the same effect after 6th click
      $("img").eq(clickCount).attr('src', '\car.jpg'); 
      clickCount++;
     }else{
        clickCount=0;
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clickCounter = 0;
    $(function()
    {
        $('#park1').on('click',function()
        {

            if(clickCounter >= $('#myDiv span').length)
            {
                clickCounter = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                clickCounter++;
            }
            $("img").eq(clickCounter).attr('src', '\car.jpg');
        });

    });
</script>
<div id="myDiv">
    <span class="fwheeler"><img src="car1.jpg"/></span>
    <span class="fwheeler"><img src="car1.jpg"/></span>
    <span class="fwheeler"><img src="car1.jpg"/></span>
    <span class="fwheeler"><img src="car1.jpg"/></span>
    <span class="fwheeler"><img src="car1.jpg"/></span>
</div>

<button type="button" id="park1">Park</button>
```

what i did is used `.on()` that allow to add events on dynamically loaded `DOM`.

I declared `clickCounter` as `global` variable so second and third and etc `click` event can use its previous value.

And counted if `clickCounter` is `equal` or `greater` than DOM image available then it will set it to 0.

Comment: all answers are correct. which should i mark as correct answer?

Comment: @RanadheerReddy its up to you bro...choose anyone if you feel thats the one help you more

Answer (score 1):

Try with this one:

```
$('#park1').click(function () {
    $('img[src$="car.jpg"]').first().attr('src', '\car.jpg');
});
```

#### [CHECKOUT THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DxkcQ/)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var clickCount=0;

(function() {

$("park1").click(function() {
$("myDiv").find("img").eq(clickCount).attr('src','/car.jpg');
clickCount++;    
});

});
```

Comment: If you placed the `clickCount++` at the end of the `.click()` function you wouldn't need to set the clickCount to -1. It would make more sense to set it to 0?

Comment: Haha yeah I know,thanks for pointing it out.Should I change it?I think I will.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
.NewImage
{
content:url("\car.jpg");
}
```

**Code**

```
   $(span).each(function(){

    if ($(this img).hasClass('NewImage') == false)
       {
         $(this img).addclass('NewImage')
         return false;
       }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using jquery use first();